# Hiding rows using CSS instead of removing the node with DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I hide rows (using `display:none`) in a table using DataTables, following a search instead of removing the node?

The reason: in each row, I have a checkbox that I want to be able to send the value even when the rows are hidden (following a search). By default, if I check a field and change page in my table, the value will not be sent at all.

Comment: Replace whatever is deleting the node with .hide()

Comment: This is how dataTables internally do it when you filter / search. You can then programmatically hide rows by fnFiler(), the recommeded way (if you ask me) - or inspect the dataTables sourcecode and replicate the same code for your needs. But it is hard to help without code example.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a precise answer without seeing more code.

Basically, instead of accessing the `table` node for your data, you should access it through datatable's api : `fnGetData` / `fnAddData` / `fnUpdate` / `fnDeleteRow` (see the [documentation](http://datatables.net/api))

Answer (score 0):

You can add CSS to all cells on a particular row like this.

Say, you want to add `visibility: hidden` to all the cells on row `1`:

```
var table = $("#my-table-element").DataTable();
$(table.row( 1 ).node())
    .find("td")
    .css("visibility", "hidden");
```